# I need php5, what version of NOOBS shall i download

Tags: noobs, setup, php

I just installed NOOBS onto the SD card but I have just messed it up, it wasn't right for me anyway since I needed php5, and the latest NOOBS comes with php7. How can I install NOOBS so that I can install php5?

Comment: PHP5 is only receiving security updates. Why do you need php7 and why won't the newer version work?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I am currently at Uni and the Pis are part of a project. We are required to use Php5 and not any other version.

Comment: Tell your professor that PHP5 is quickly going the way of the dodo and PHP7 is what industry will be expecting you to know...

Answer (score 2):

If you really need php5, add the `jessie` to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
$ sudo -s

# echo "deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install php5
```

However, you should be advised that php5 is old news.

Answer (score 2):

NOOBS will only install the latest Raspbian, if you need an obsolete version you will need to install Raspbian, which you can find on https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/images/

You might get away with an old NOOBS from https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/NOOBS/archive/

Mind you PHP7 has been the standard release on most distributions for 2 years; it is only Debian which has not changed until recently.